# Best way to iterate second time of Set inside a loop in Java?

Tags: java

Below is the current code which works fine

```
    Set<Employee> employeeSet = inCompanyBean.getEmployees();
    Set<Employee> innerEmployeeSet = employeeSet;

    Iterator<Employee> iter = employeeSet.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
         Employee formerEmp = iter.next();
         Iterator<Employee> itLater = innerEmployeeSet.iterator();
         while(itLater.hasNext()){
            Employee laterEmployee = itLater.next();
            // do the processing
         }
     }

    }
```

Basically want to compare values from each object with remaining objects.

Example,
     If 5 Employee objects are there, comparison will be as follows
        1st object - compare with all the objects values
        2nd objects - compare with all the objects values
        3rd object - compare with all the objects values

The above logic works fine.

However i would like to know the best way to achieve the performance. The above takes a huge amount of memory.

Thanks.

Comment: *"The above takes a huge amount of memory."* Huh? I don't see any significant memory use above at all.

Comment: Is the above is an efficient way or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The above has the issue that it repeats a lot of comparisons. But again: You've claimed this uses a lot of **memory**. I don't see any reason it would.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to accomplish?  You say it works fine but we don't see the terminal "comparison" logic.

Comment: What is your end goal? Your code has complexity O(n^2). If you _really_ need to do something with each element against each one of the others, then there is not a more efficient way of doing it. But depending on your end goal, you may not need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested loop itself doesn't appear to be intrinsically memory hungry - perhaps it's just the unshown code that's consuming memory?

That said, why not use the modern `for` syntax and make your code massively more readable:

```
Set<Employee> employeeSet = inCompanyBean.getEmployees();

for (Employee outer : employeeSet) {
    for (Employee inner : employeeSet) {
        if (inner == outer) continue;

        // do the processing
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if `proc(a, b)` gives the same result as `proc(b, a)` and `proc(a, a)` is a no-op then you can half the number of processing operations by only having the inner loop iterate from one more than the outer loop's current position, which unfortunately isn't possible without using explicit indices:

```
Set<Employee> employeeSet = inCompanyBean.getEmployees();
Employee[] employees = employeeSet.toArray(new Employee[0]);
int n = employees.length;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    Employee outer = employees[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {   // note start value of 'j'
        Employee inner = employees[j];

        // do the processing
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible to halve the number of operations if you call inner.iterator() outside of the loops. That way each element is only compared with every other one once.

Answer (score 1):

Just try converting set to list and iterate based on index like:

```
Set<Employee> empSet= new HashSet<Employee>();
empSet.add(...);
List<Employee> empList= new ArrayList<Employee>(empSet);
for (int i =0;i<empList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j =0;j<empList.size(); j++) {
        if (i==j) {
            continue;
        }
        if (empList.get(i).compareTo(empList.get(j)) > 0) {//do something
        }
    }
}
```